# Document.addEventListener "this" context

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, dom-events

I'm writing a simple CoffeeScript class, but I'm running into a context issue with this code:

```
class DragDrop
constructor: (@selector, @bodyDragEnterClass = "drag-over") ->
    @attachEventHandlers()

attachEventHandlers: () ->
    document.write(@bodyDragEnterClass) # this line tells me, that @bodyDragEnterClass is "drag-over"
    document.addEventListener("dragenter", @onDragEnter, false)

onDragEnter: () ->
    document.write(@bodyDragEnterClass) # this line tells me, that @bodyDragEnterClass is undefined
    jQuery("body").addClass(@bodyDragEnterClass)

window.DragDrop = DragDrop
```

When the `attachEventHandlers` method is called, the `@bodyDragEnterClass` is set to "drag-over" as expected. However when the `dragenter` event is triggered, and `onDragEnter` method is called, the `@bodyDragEnterClass` is "undefined".

I've created a jsfiddle to demonstrate the context problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/SVvrM/

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a classic case for the "[fat arrow](http://coffeescript.org/#fat_arrow)" in CoffeeScript.

You need to access the your DragDrop `this` value within a callback that is executed in a different context. Using the fat arrow will bind the current value of `this` to your `onDragEnter` function:

```
# "fat arrow" function binding
onDragEnter: () =>
  document.write(@bodyDragEnterClass) # this line tells me, that @bodyDragEnterClass is undefined
  jQuery("body").addClass(@bodyDragEnterClass)
```

Comment: @Martin This is the way you get around context in CS, but you should understand what it does under the hood. Paste the fat arrow code into the online CS repl and see how it sets `self = this`